# Why does my Qt desktop application open in the nokia simulator when running from xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, qt-creator, qmake

Just decided that I no longer want to run Qt creator since I can't find a good way to organize my project. I decided to make my project a xcode project by using the qmake command. I opened the project in xcode 3 and it built (thank god) and then when xcode tried to launch it it launched the nokia phone simulator instead (where nothing is showing except a black screen inside of the simulator. that is, when it doesn't crash ofc) For some reason my app is now a nokia phone app and the *.app file crashes when I try to run it without the simulator. 
I then tried to open the project in xcode 4 and the exact same thing happened.

My project build perfectly in Qt creator but I find it too hard to work with. For example, I can find no way of creating subfolders to organize big projects and my marker disappears when I write something and I have to mark some text (which is pretty tricky since I cannot locate my marker) for my mouse/marker to reappear.

So does anyone have any idea how to run a desktop app in xcode? Any settings I missed?

Comment: What are your qmake args, what is in your *.pro file?